# Add new template for refinery CMS

Tags: templates, refinerycms

How to fix the issue `Can't add the new template in Refinery CMS`? We add flow by [the guide](http://refinerycms.com/guides/using-custom-view-or-layout-templates).  The new template display successfully in port 3000 but not display port 80. We're using `nginx` and `unicorn` server and `capistrano` plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: because capistrano need to create build again. We can't change from original source. If you don't want build again, you have to the source code that built and change in this source.